# Adding default parameter to Powershell Core script

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am very much new to Powershell and I am trying to add a default value to two parameters in a script file but I am still being asked to enter the missing parameter at execution.

The parameters are

```
param(
    [string]
    $Build = "production",

    [bool]
    $Deploy = 1
)
```

So when I do `./script.ps1 -Build` I get an error as

```
/Users/akshayrajgollahalli/GitHub/gollahalli.com/script.ps1 : Missing an argument for parameter 'Build'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
```

But according to the Microsoft [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/create-and-use-default-values-in-powershell-scripts/) that is what I am doing. I am not sure what's the mistake here.

**Update 1:**

Another case would be I might want something like `./script.ps1 -Build local` which should override the `production` value.

Comment: If you simply leave out the `-Build` parameter in your function call, the script will use the default value `"production"`. If you DO use the parameter, you must also supply a value.

Comment: @Theo Am I not doing that, if I leave `-Build` without any extra input it should be taking in production as default right? but that's not happening

Comment: I might want something like `-Build local`, which should not use "production"

Comment: No, with optional parameters like this, you do NOT append the `-Build` to the call. If you do, Powershell expects a value for that parameter. If you want the script to use `"local"` for the `$Build` variable, then you use it. In other words: using the script like this: `./script.ps1` will take the default value of "production" for the `$Build` variable.

Comment: oh! ok. If you could answer that, I will mark it answered. Thanks though

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When defining optional parameters with a default value, you can either leave out the parameter in the call to have the script use this default value, or use it to have the script use something else instead of the default value.

As an example. This script will simply output whatever is used for the `$Build` and `$Deploy` parameters:

```
param(
    [string]
    $Build = "production",

    [bool]
    $Deploy = 1
)

Write-Host "Using Build value:  $Build"
Write-Host "Using Deploy value: $Deploy"
```

If I use it like this:

```
& 'D:\script1.ps1'
```

It does not receive any alternative values for $Build and $Deploy, so the output will be:

> ```
> Using Build value:  production
> Using Deploy value: True
> ```

Whenever you would like to run the script with values other that their defaults, you add the parameter(s) and value(s) to the call like this:

```
& 'D:\script1.ps1' -Build "something else"
```

Output:

> ```
> Using Build value:  something else
> Using Deploy value: True
> ```

Hope this explains